# Inserting an increment number that initializes based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table that looks like this:

```
QNo  |  ANo   | Some Text Column
-----------------------------------
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
```

What I'd like to do in a stored procedure is fill the middle column with an incrementing that initializes whenever the first column changes value such as this:

```
QNo  |  ANo   |  Some Text Column
-----------------------------------
1   |     1
1   |     2
1   |     3
1   |     4
2   |     1
2   |     2
2   |     3
2   |     4
3   |     1
3   |     2
3   |     3
3   |     4
```

This needs to be done at insert time because the column is part of the PK along with QNo. It is always 4 it will never go less or more.

Is there a way to do it? other than using a loop or iterating?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your table does not have an identifier column? any Id?

Comment: i think you can use trigger for this, if you don't want it to be in your insert query.

Comment: it is kind of a lookup to fill in parts of the main table. If I have to I can add an identity but right now, no.

Comment: Why does this need to be always from 1 - 4?  This suggests a relationship between the storage and presentation of your data that's probably not correct.  Usually, you just want to show an ordinal number (your 1 - 4) on _display_.  The db doesn't actually care which ones they are.

Comment: How do you decide which combo of `QNo` and `Some Text Column` becomes `ANo` 1,2,3,4? does that matter? How is this table populated in general? What are you trying to accomplish? IS this a one time need or ongoing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching for this

```
SELECT QNo, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QNo ORDER BY ANo) AS IncrementalNo
FROM   TABLE
```

Comment: BTW,what you are up-to ?@brykneval query is OK.but that is about select.
Is your table normalize. will hold what ?explain the requirement of insert.you hv what at the time of insertion .

Comment: @KumarHarsh I am trying to answer the question rather than normalize and also if he gets the requirement ok with a select, do he really need to insert that data??

Comment: sorry i questioned YaserQ8.I said @brykneval 's query is ok.I guess yes,he need to store data in that manner .YaserQ8 can only clarify further .

Comment: that is exactly what I needed brykneval. I am sorry I could not participate earlier. Someone rated my question down and for a while I couldn't see anything added anymore. Seems back now. I am new to this website.